# Changing hundreds of column names simultaneously in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with hundreds of columns whose names I want to change. I'm very new to R, so it's rather easy to think through the logic of this, but I simply can't find a relevant example online.

The closest I could sort of get was this:

```
projectFileAllCombinedNames <- for (i in 1:200){names(projectFileAllCombined)[i+1] <-variableNames[i]}
```

Basically, starting at the second column of projectFileAllCombined, I want to loop through the columns in the dataframe and assign them the data values in the second data frame. I was able to change one column name manually with this code:

```
colnames(projectFileAllCombined)[2]<-"newColumnName"
```

but I can't possibly do that for hundreds of columns. I've spent multiple hours on this and can't crack it with any number of Google searches on "change multiple columns in r" or "change column names in r". The best I can find online is examples where people change a few columns with a c() function and I get how that works, but that still seems to require typing out all the column names as parameters to the function, unless there is a way to just pass the "variableNames" file into that c() function, but I don't know of one.

Comment: There is a function in base `colnames` which will give you the colnames of an object. There is an associated function `colnames<-` which will allow you to assign column names.

Answer (score 1):

Will

```
colnames(projectFileAllCombined)[-1] <- variableNames
```

not suffice?

This assumes the ordering of columns in `projectFileAllCombined` is the same as the ordering of the new variable names in `variableNames`, and that

```
length(variableNames) == (ncol(projectFileAllCombined) - 1)
```

The key point here is that the replacement function `'colnames<-'()` is vectorised and can replace any number of column names in a single call *if* passed a vector of replacement values.